# Weird libobjc.a.dylib objc_msgsend crash

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Search anywhere and could not found an answer. I have this issue causing the app to crash on many users.

How many?

[image]

**MANY!**

I can't reproduce the crash and I can't understand anything from the Crashlytics logs:

[image]

After reading some questions and answers around I suspect that something in ManagedObjectContext cause it.

Already visited:

1. [libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend crash occurring with core data usage in background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711332/libobjc-a-dylibobjc-msgsend-crash-occurring-with-core-data-usage-in-background)
2. [Swift Crash libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836230/swift-crash-libobjc-a-dylib-objc-msgsend)
3. [iOS crash libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357028/ios-crash-libobjc-a-dylib-objc-msgsend)
4. [Xcode 8.1 release APP crash libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134579/xcode-8-1-release-app-crash-libobjc-a-dylib-objc-msgsend)
5. [libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend crash occurring with core data usage in background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711332/libobjc-a-dylibobjc-msgsend-crash-occurring-with-core-data-usage-in-background)

What should I do next?

Crash log:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1b0e720f8 objc_msgSend + 24
1  Foundation                     0x19dcb3b90 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 188
2  CoreFoundation                 0x19c89c76c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
3  CoreFoundation                 0x19c89c668 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
4  CoreFoundation                 0x19c89b9cc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
5  CoreFoundation                 0x19c895a8c __CFRunLoopRun + 824
6  CoreFoundation                 0x19c89521c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
7  GraphicsServices               0x1b3914784 GSEventRunModal + 164
8  UIKitCore                      0x19f2ce200 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072
9  UIKitCore                      0x19f2d3a74 UIApplicationMain + 168
10 ZoomQuizProd                   0x102a407b0 main + 19 (AppNotificationManager.swift:19)
11 libdyld.dylib                  0x19c5556c0 start + 4
```

Comment: Since you included the `core-data` tag, what part of this seems to be connected to Core Data?

Comment: I think that it has to do with the saving/creating of objects. I'm not really sure, but this is what i've read in other questions/answers. Look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38725924/1138498

Comment: In that case the person had connected the crash to a function that was using Core Data.

Comment: I guess, but for me no function creating the crush and I could not reproduce it. I just see it in the Crashlytics logs.. So what could cause it?

Comment: I don't know. But when tracking down the cause of a crash, it's important to not narrow your focus without a good reason. It might be Core Data related but it could be something else-- nothing you've posted points to any particular framework. You probably need to gather more information about when these crashes occur. If you can narrow down what situations lead to crashes, you may be able to narrow down the part of the app that's causing them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to narrow down as much as possible, but I wasn't enable to reproduce the crash. Just can't understand when it happens. Do you have any recommendation of a tool that can help me figure out the cause?